# Discontinuous jumps in phases from complex demodulation

Tags: demodulation

I am using complex demodulation to estimate slow amplitude
and phase changes over time of a single sinusoid. The time
series consists of continuous blocks with large gaps (~30%
of block lengths) between them. The amplitude results are fine,
but although the estimated phase evolution is smooth within blocks,
there are sometimes large jumps (of different sizes) when going from
one block to the next. This is *not* due to +/- 2pi ambiguities: the
results lie roughly in (-2,2) and the jumps vary in size from ~0.2 to
~1.5. Within a block the phase typically varies by ~0.1; the blocks
are long enough that independent statistical testing (Nyblom statistic)
confirms that changes within blocks are significant.

Additional requested information: the gaps between data are
due to extraneous circumstances, not connected to the source
of the sinusoids. The same time zeropoint is used throughout.
Besides all this, I replicated the problem using simulated
data with *no* changes in phase: using the observed times
(blocks and gaps), and generating a pure sinusoid with constant
amplitude and phase, I still obtain apparent phase jumps
after some gaps using complex demodulation. The result should
therefore be reproducible.

The model is
$$y(t)=A\cos(2\pi f t+\phi)+\sigma e(t),\;\; t=1,2,...$$
where $e$ is standard normal.
Here are some specific parameter values: block lengths 500;
gap lengths 167;  $A=15$, $f=0.105269$, $\phi=1.7$; $\sigma=1.5$.
With these fixed block and gap lengths I get phase jumps
after every gap; in my application the block and gap
lengths vary somewhat and I don't get noticeable jumps after
each gap.

The low pass filtering is performed by two passes of a
moving average filter with length $2P+1$, where $P=9$ is
the nearest integer to $1/f$.

Comment: So you would expect a phase change within a gap of less than 0.1 radian.  Can you be certain that whatever mechanism is causing the gaps is not also causing a change in the phase of your sampling clock?  Can you _edit your question_ with the pertinent information about why there are gaps, especially if there's anything that may cause timing jumps in your sampling?

Comment: And while I'm at it -- are you taking into account the time jumps from one block to the next?  I.e. if you're just treating the beginning of each block as $t = 0$, then unless you're dealing with sinusoids that are guaranteed to be aligned with the start of each block, you're going to get odd results.

Comment: Chris- If I understand your update correctly, you are saying that you can simulate the effect you see by using a pure sinusoid, inducing gaps and reproducing the apparent jumps in phase due to your approach of complex demodulation? If that is accurate, could you share the specific details of your simulation in a way that it can be reproduced? I think that will help get to a reasonable explanation for what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer lies in the large uncertainty
when estimating the starting phase from a relatively
short time series.